# mysql returning 2 different columns from the same field but with different conditions

Tags: mysql

How can I return 2 columns from the same field with different conditions, these are the two conditions:

```
SELECT CITY,REGION,SALES FROM SALESREPS WHERE SALES < QUOTA;

SELECT CITY,REGION,SALES FROM SALESREPS WHERE SALES > QUOTA;
```

I mean some say that I just need to put 'AND'. Well what I need is a 1 line code from that example that will return 2 different sales columns. 1st column will be the sales < quota and the other column is the sales > quota. All of these are from the same table.

Comment: so this is not what you're looking for? SELECT CITY,REGION,SALES FROM SALESREPS WHERE SALES < QUOTA and SALES > QUOTA;

Comment: @davejal Can't be. because that cannot return any data, since `SALES` cannot both be less than `QUOTA` **and** greater than `QUOTA`.

Comment: True, but from his question I can't understand what he wants, a union would give him everything also

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mySql if statement like the following:

```
SELECT 
    CITY,
    REGION,
    SALES,
    IF (SALES < QUOTA,SALES,null) as BELOW_QUOTA,
    IF (SALES > QUOTA,SALES,null) as ABOVE_QUOTA
    FROM SALESREPS;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CITY,REGION,IF(SALES < QUOTA, SALES) AS  LessThanColumn, IF(Sales > QUOTA, Sales) AS GreaterThanColumn  FROM SALESREPS

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want 4 columns (`CITY`, `REGION`, `LOW_SALES`, `HIGH_SALES`), with data for every row but only one of `LOW_SALES` and `HIGH_SALES` have a value (the other is null), then you can:

```
select CITY
     , REGION
     , case when SALES < QUOTA then SALES end as LOW_SALES
     , case when SALES > QUOTA then SALES end as HIGH_SALES
  from SALESREPS;
```

The SQL statement uses database agnostic syntax, so it'll work on databases other than MySQL.

This can also be done with a `union`:

```
select CITY, REGION, SALES as LOW_SALES, null as HIGH_SALES
  from SALESREPS
 where SALES < QUOTA
union all
select CITY, REGION, null as LOW_SALES, SALES as HIGH_SALES
 from SALESREPS
 where SALES > QUOTA;
```

Neither makes much sense to me, e.g. what about rows with `SALES = QUOTA`?

Now, if you want totals for `CITY`/`REGION`, that makes more sense to me (including exact equal in `HIGH_SALES`):

```
select CITY
     , REGION
     , sum(case when SALES < QUOTA then SALES else 0 end) as LOW_SALES
     , sum(case when SALES >= QUOTA then SALES else 0 end) as HIGH_SALES
  from SALESREPS
 group by CITY
        , REGION;
```

If you just want counts instead:

```
select CITY
     , REGION
     , sum(case when SALES < QUOTA then 1 else 0 end) as LOW_SALES
     , sum(case when SALES >= QUOTA then 1 else 0 end) as HIGH_SALES
  from SALESREPS
 group by CITY
        , REGION;
```